# ReferenceError: document is not defined(javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation, localhost, visual-studio-code-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWmbM.png)Why after installing node.js, an error like that occurs after I run the code of various javascript commands, it seems it's not because the code is an error but because node.js doesn't want to connect to the server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPc9i.png)When I tried to check whether node.js was connected to localhost or not, it turned out it wasn't connected, so how do I get node.js to connect to 127.0.0.1:300?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, data, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: `document` is a predefined global on browsers. The Node.js environment doesn't have that global, because it's not a browser.

Comment: Looking at the image of code, it seems you are using vanilla js with HTML and CSS. You can install `Live Server` extension in VS Code and run `index.html` using Live Server.  It will open `index.html` file in browser. If `index.js` file connected to `index.html` file then you will see value of `x` in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your JavaScript file in node.js enviroment. The document object and its methods, like getElementById in your case, are part of the Web API provided by browsers for manipulating web pages and are not available in Node.js.

Why?
Because, node.js is a JS runtime used primarily for server-side scripting and does not have a built-in Document Object Model (DOM) like a web browser does

You can read more about the Document interface here: [Document API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

To run your js script in the browser, add it as a script in your index.html file with the `<script>` tag. This will load your javascript when your HTML file is loaded in the browser. You can follow the steps mentioned here:

[Use JavaScript within a webpage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_JavaScript_within_a_webpage)